# List to Port Using Def Function (Python)

Tags: python, function

I'm having trouble understanding this assignment. I'm currently learning about using define function (Sorry I'm very new to Python). And although I know how to use the define function, I don't quite understand how to attack this problem.

I understand how the def function works, but correct me if I am wrong, how can you correct the list by changing Keelung instead of Kaoshung? Doesn't that use if else function? I'm having a very hard time attacking this problem, and if any clues as to how would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

> Make a List of the ports a certain ship plans to call at:
>
> - Oakland
> - Long Beach
> - Hong Kong
> - Kaohsiung
> - Naha
> - Yokohama
> - Oakland
>
> Allow the user to correct the list by telling you, by number, the new port in the itinerary.
>
> For a demo, correct the list to call at Keelung instead of Kaohsiung.

This is what I have so far...

```
   def change_list ():
   n = raw_input("pos:")
   new = raw_input("new:")
   num_list[int(n)] = new

   if __name__ == "__main__":
   change_list()
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what are the expected and the actual results? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you defined the requirements for the program yet?

Comment: @Tichodroma, can you direct me as to how I would start? I'm just completely lost, and would like to start off some place where I can get some help, and I will edit when I make the code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, so basically I need to make a list of the ports which described on top. And then I need to correct the list to call at Keelung instead of Koaslung as an example.

Comment: Incorrect. Try again, reading every word of every sentence this time.

Comment: I'm sorry you are lost, but this kind of question is not what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people won't do your homework for you, (probably the reason why you already have a downvote) but from what I understand of your question it seems fairly simple,

It seems to me you want to create a method that asks for a position in the list and asks for a new city or w.e

```
def change_list ():
    n = raw_input("pos:")
    new = raw_input("new:")
    num_list[int(n)] = new

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change_list()
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a list: use the `list()` function or list comprehenshion []

example

```
aList = ['a','b','c']
```

Accessing a list element:

```
print(aList[1])
-> b
```

That should hopefully get you on your way